# static initialization in java

Tags: java, jvm

I know there are a lot of questions similar to this one , but i would like to get some detailed explanation about this issue.

Let say that i have this code -

```
 public class Finalexamples {

        public int num = 3;
        public static int num2;
        public static Finalexamples a;

        public Finalexamples(){
            Finalexamples.num2 = 4;
        }

        static{
            a = new Finalexamples();
             System.out.println(num2);
             Finalexamples.num2 = 5;
            }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting...");
    }

}
```

1. When the JVM loads a .class file, does it first initialize the static variables with a default value, and afterward when the program running with the literal value?
2. In my example, the static block outputs "4" (fixed), if one can explain why isn't it 0?

Comment: Do you mean it outputs "4"?

Comment: In your program static block outputs 4 not 3. Why do you believe that the field assignment would be run after the static block ?

Comment: No, it doesn't print 3. There is no way it can print 3, since the code never initializes num2 to 3.

Comment: Sorry guys , of course 4.

Comment: OK. Why do you think it should output 0, given that the constructor is run just before the println, and the constructor initializes the value to 4?

Comment: When loading the class , based on what i know the static blocks and varibles and read and exectuted first. but when the constructor is initialized?

Comment: `a = new Finalexamples();`: that calls your constructor. Before printing num2.

Comment: Static blocks are initialized when class is loaded. There are no "funny" rules, it travels top to bottom and jumps into methods and constructors where it again travels top to bottom - in your case, constructor is invoked first, its invokation sets `num2` to "4", and then you print it.

Comment: @M. Prokhorov, Static _initialization_ blocks are  not run when the class is loaded, they're run when the class is initialized, as the term "initialization block" indicates. Initialization occurs after loading, potentially long after.

Comment: @Barak michaeli You should never initialize static elements from constructors, nor constructors of a class from its own static initialization blocks, and especially not both at once.

Comment: It's also a bad idea to do logic not pertinent to initialization, such as the `println` in your example, in an initialization block.

Comment: @LewBloch thanks. well the output was just for demostration. so the static blocks and static varibles initialized after the class was loading and just before my main function start to run?

Comment: The JLS lays out the intialization sequence in excruciating detail. Read the Fine Manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so first Java goes to your topmost static declaration in the class (defining `num2` As an int) then it defines `a` as a `Finalexamples` object. It then goes to your static block. In the static block, it sees `a = new Finalexamples();` so it then goes to create `a` via the constructor. (If it didn't do this step until the end of static initialization, `a` would be inaccessible until the end, since it wasn't constructed, which is not good!) So in our constructor for the variable `a` we set `Finalexamples.num2` equal to 4. The constructor is done and Java returns to executing the static block, and prints out `Finalexamples.num2`, which is now 4.

Answer (score 3):

Why `0` ? It should output `4` rather.

When the class is loaded, the static fields and statements are read and executed in the order of apparition.

So these are executed first :

```
public static int num2;
public static Finalexamples a;
```

Then this is invoked :

```
 static{
          a = new Finalexamples();
          System.out.println(num2);
          Finalexamples.num2 = 5;
      }
```

This :  `a = new Finalexamples();` executes : `Finalexamples.num2 = 4;`

So  `System.out.println(num2);` displays `4`

Comment: Are you sure, that `public int num = 3;` is executed on loading the class? I would think it's first executed when the instance is created in the static block.

Comment: I am sure it is not :) Thank you for the remark. (copy paste is the hell...)

Answer (score 0):

Know this flow first(this is for your program only),

1. Initialization of static variable.

   ```
   public static int num2;
   public static Finalexamples a;
   ```
2. Execution of static block:

   ```
   static{
       a = new Finalexamples();
        System.out.println(num2);
        Finalexamples.num2 = 5;
       }
   ```
3. As you are initializing the object reference 'a' of  `Finalexamples` in static block, the constructor of Finalexamples class will be called.

   ```
   public Finalexamples(){
               Finalexamples.num2 = 4;
     }
   ```
4. The Finalexamples.main() method. Which has nothing.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println("Starting...");
       }
   ```

Answering your questions.

A. Static variables are initialized only once , at the start of the execution .These variables will be initialized first, before the initialization of any instance variables. It is a variable which belongs to the class and not to object(instance). A single copy to be shared by all instances of the class

B. It's not `'0'` becuase you are initializing the object reference in static block with new object of Finalexamples. At this time the constructor will be called and it will set the vaule of `num2` to `4`.

I hope this help!

Comment: "at the start of execution" , do u mean when the classloader loads this class? , or that the classloader loads the all  .class and then initialize?

Comment: Yep. When the class loads

Comment: So when the constructor is loaded? right after the class variables?

Comment: When you create a object i.e when you call "new Finalexamples()". The () this a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

hi your final output is 5
in java you two section first is Class Area and second is Heap area 
class area block contains three block 
method area,static area,constant pool.static block is run when class loading so your static variable is created in static block it is initialize at the run time of static block and for static variable multiple copy will not created in java so you can test your code like this

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public int num = 3;
    public static int num2;
    public static HelloWorld a;

    public HelloWorld(){
         System.out.println("Constructor Creation value of num2 "+num2);
         HelloWorld.num2 = 4;
         System.out.println("Variable Initialization in Constructor value of num2 "+num2);
    }

    static{

         System.out.println("Static bloack execution  value of num2 "+num2);
          a = new HelloWorld();
         HelloWorld.num2 = 5;
         System.out.println("Variable Initialization in Static bloack value of num2 "+num2);
        }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Starting...");
}}
```